# How can I reference a specific row(s) in a data frame using an instance of a column variable in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say I have the following data frame in r:

```
> patientData
        patientID age diabetes    status
      1         1  25   Type 1      Poor
      2         2  34   Type 2  Improved
      3         3  28   Type 1 Excellent
      4         4  52   Type 1      Poor
```

How can I reference a specific row or group of rows by using the specific value/level of a particular column rather than the row index?  For instance, if I wanted to set a variable x to equal all of the rows which contain a patient with Type 1 diabetes or all of the rows that contain a patient in "Improved" status, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    library(dplyr)

    patientData %>%
      filter(diabetes == "Type 1")
```

Next time, [please provide a Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).